# Regex pattern recognition in react input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex

I am trying to validate an email address on the client side and the form keeps on telling me that I don't have the required pattern to submit. I want the email input to end with "@gmail.com".

```js
const CreatePeople = () => {
  return (
    <div className="people-form">
      <form action="#" id="create-people-form">
        <label htmlFor="create-people-email">Email</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          id="create-people-email"
          pattern="@gmail.com$"
          required
        />
        // unnecessary stuff
        <button type="submit">Finish</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pattern=.+@gmail.com$` instead.

Your pattern has to match the full value of the input.